# How to run WordCount in Amazon EMR?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

What is the proper way of specifying input and output path in Amazon EMR ?

In my cluster, I clicked `Add Step` then select Custom Jar and input the jar location `s3://wordcountbuckett/wc.jar` . For the arguments input box, I have specified `s3://wordcountbuckett/file01` as my input file and `s3://wordcountbuckett/output/` as my output path.

file01 is a txt file whereas /output/ is a folder.

Below is the error that I obtained from the logs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: s3://wordcountbuckett/
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

My Add Step details:
1. Step Type : Custom Jar
2. Name : WordCount2
3. JAR Location : s3://mywordcountbuckett/binary/wc.jar
4. Arguments: s3://mywordcountbuckett/input/
s3://mywordcountbuckett/output/
5. Action on Failure : Continue
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Custom Jar step?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I was unable to upload the screenshot but the steps are as edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have specified the correct paths? Because in the text you talk about `s3://wordcountbuckett/wc.jar` but in your add step configuration you specify `s3://mywordcountbuckett/..`. I suggest checking whether this is the problem or just a typo.